# How to keep user logged in on refresh of dashboard page using firebase onAuthStateChange in a react app and react router dom RouterProvider API

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom, dataloader

I am using react router dom RouterProvider which decouples fetching from rendering, from the official remix-run react router example of auth-router-provider, it was stated in the `README.md` that

> we can no longer rely on React context and/or hooks to get our user authentication status. We need access to this information outside of the React tree so we can use it in our route loader and action functions. https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples/auth-router-provider

I created a standalone object outside of the React tree that manages my authentication state for `login and logout`, my object structure looks like

```
export const authProvider: AuthProvider = {
  user: null,

  async login(email: string, password: string) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        authProvider.user = userCredential.user;
        return redirect("/dashboard");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        return toast.error("Password or Email invalid");
      });
  },

  async signout() {
    signOut(auth);
    authProvider.user = null;
  },
};
```

I import the standalone object my loader file and return `authProvider.user` in my dashboard loader

```
loader() {
  return { user: authProvider.user };
}
```

the user is access using the `useRouteLoaderData` in the dashboard component

```
const {user} = useRouteLoaderData("dashboard")
```

the user will be initially null and I can navigate else where if the user is not logged in, but when a user is logged in the user is no longer null and can view the dashboard page, but when i refresh the dashboard page after a user login the user always return null.

I can't seem to get right where i will use the `onAuthStateChange` from firebase because i was using it inside a `useEffect` earlier when i was managing user with react context.

I need assistnace on how to make the user persist on refresh of the dashboard page.

Comment: @Drew Reese I am trying to use the RouterProvider and from the example provided by react-router in their documentation the loader is used to return the user if signed in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `authProvider` object to include a function that can call Firebase's `onAuthStateChanged` function to check the current user's authentication status. Wrap the call in a Promise that resolves when the `onAuthStateChanged` succeeds, or rejects in the failure case.

```js
import {
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();

interface AuthProvider {
  user: User | null;
  checkAuth(): Promise<void>;
  login(email: string, password: string): Promise<void>;
  signout(): Promise<void>;
}

export const authProvider: AuthProvider = {
  user: null,

  checkAuth: async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      onAuthStateChanged(
        auth,
        (user) => {
          authProvider.user = user; // User | null
          resolve();
        },
        reject
      );
    });
  },
  login: async (email: string, password: string) => {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        authProvider.user = userCredential.user;
        return redirect("/dashboard");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        return toast.error("Password or Email invalid");
      });
  },
  signout: async () => {
    signOut(auth);
    authProvider.user = null;
  },
};
```

Call your `authProvider` instance's `checkAuth` function and wait for it to settle.

```js
loader = async () => {
  try {
    await authProvider.checkAuth();
    return {
      user: authProvider.user
    };
  } catch(error) {
    // handle/ignore error
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @Drew, the code works now

Comment: @AbdulbasitYusuf Welcome, glad to help. Did this answer address/resolve your question/issue?

Comment: Yes, the answer resolve the issue but i noticed signing out the user with ```authProvider.signout``` does not sign out the user as the user returned from the loader still return the firebase ```user``` instead of ```null```

Comment: @AbdulbasitYusuf There isn't much code here with regards to signing out. Does the user actually get signed out in the backend in Firebase so the next time the route loader and `checkAuth` is called that the correct authentication information is returned and set in the `authProvider` object? I could check myself, but is `signOut` also `async` where you may want to wait for it to settle before updating the `authProvider.user` value? Does there need to be *some* React state involved here such that a React component rerender is effected so the app can see the updated user value?

Comment: @AbdulbasitYusuf Can you edit your post to include where and how your `login` and `signout` functions are used?

Comment: I figured out the issue while editing the question and going through the code, I was calling the ```signout``` in a link tag, I changed the tag to a button now and it works fine, thanks for your time